# doctrine2 criteria - like operator

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, criteria, sql-like

i use doctrine2 in zf2 as orm. i have a query builder object to which add doctrine criteria instance.

i would obtain like operator in where condition. for this i use following

```
$criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->contains('name',$this->container['srcName']));
```

i get Unknown comparison operator: CONTAINS

if use

```
$criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('name',$this->container['srcName']));
```

no exception throw but it isn't result that i want

Comment: the code is exactly what i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok the problem is the version of module.

i update module with composer in this way

```
"doctrine/doctrine-module": "0.9.*@dev",
"doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*@dev",
"doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.9.*@dev",
```